# CSS border property not working in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

Below code is not working in IE but working in Chrome...

```
$(this).css("border","solid 1px green")
```

Please someone help me.

Comment: Can you give more context?  And which version of IE are you talking about?  More than 1 line of code would be nice.

Comment: Can we see your HTML too please? Also which version of IE?

Comment: Works fine for me in IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/faAcf/  you may need to include more detail.  What is `this` in your real code, what css is already attached to it, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).css({borderTop: '1px solid green'});
$(this).css({borderLeft: '1px solid green'});
$(this).css({borderRight: '1px solid green'});
$(this).css({borderBottom: '1px solid green'});
```

I think this is something I ran into before and I had to declare each border edge.

---

Instead of that, why not just create a class called `green` like so:

`.green { border: 1px solid green; }`

Then do

`$(this).addClass('green');`

Comment: You could merge the objects together - that's what's so neat about passing objects to functions like `.css` :)

Comment: If it was me having problems with something like this I would simply just `addClass('green');` with the border on that class.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work just fine for IE7+ versions ..

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/jHK8q/

Are you sure `this` points to an element ? (*are you calling this code from an event handler?*)